# Cloud-Init systemd-networkd bridge configuration incomplete/incorrect

Tags: networking, arch-linux, bridge, systemd-networkd, cloud-init

When using Cloud-Init on ArchLinux, which uses systemd-networkd to configure network interfaces, for bridge interfaces, the configuration files generated are incomplete/incorrect. After a very long boot delay, the bridge interface fails to come online. I have to modify the generated files, even creating new files to get a working bridge interface.

Starting with the Cloud-Init documentation:

https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/network-config-format-v2.html#bridges

I came up with the following network YAML file:

```
version: 2
ethernets:
  switchports:
    match:
      macaddress: '00:16:3e:00:e7:1d'
bridges:
  br0:
    interfaces: [switchports]
    addresses:
      - 192.168.231.29/23
    routes:
      - to: 0.0.0.0/0
        via: 192.168.230.4
    nameservers:
      addresses: [192.168.230.5]
```

After a long boot delay, probably due to failed networking, I get the following network config files generated by Cloud-Init:

```
</etc/systemd/network/10-cloud-init-br0.network>

[Address]
Address=192.168.231.29/23

[Match]
Name=br0

[Network]
DHCP=no
DNS=192.168.230.5

[Route]
Destination=0.0.0.0/0

Gateway=192.168.230.4



</etc/systemd/network/10-cloud-init-eth0.network>

[Match]
MACAddress=00:16:3e:00:e7:1d
Name=eth0

[Network]
DHCP=no



</etc/systemd/network/10-cloud-init-switchports.network>

[Match]
Name=switchports

[Network]
DHCP=no
```

According to the systemd documentation:

https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.network.html

This the netdev file it missing. The switchport file not even close. I have to create a new netdev file and modify the other two files to look something like:

```
</etc/systemd/network/10-cloud-init-br0.netdev> #New File

[NetDev]
Name=br0
Kind=bridge

</etc/systemd/network/10-cloud-init-eth0.network> #Modify this file
[Match]
MACAddress=00:16:3e:00:e7:1d
Name=eth0
    
[Network]
DHCP=no
Bridge=br0 <- new line


</etc/systemd/network/10-cloud-init-switchports.network> #delete this file outright
```

No need to edit the main br0 config file. After running

> systemctl restart systemd-networkd.service

The br0 interface comes online. I am trying to figure out if I am doing something wrong on the cloud-init network YAML config. At the very least, the netdev file is not being generate at all. I can remove that mac address match if I really needed to, but I am hoping the Network Config V2 is more flexible than that.

In any case, Cloud-Init is not configuring the systemd-networkd bridge correctly on ArchLinux. Any help would be appreciated.